# Use mutate_at() to create multiple binary variables from the values of a single variable

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have some variables that contain the following support values {a, b, c, ... k} and I wanted to create multiple binary variables for each response. For example, `var_a` would be equivalent to `as.numeric(`variable name very long`== "a")`, `var_b` would be equivalent to `as.numeric(`variable name very long`== "b")` and so on. However, in some of the variables, they don't go neatly from a:k. Some might have skipped a letter or two.

I know how to use mutate_at when I have multiple variables that I want to change, but what if I only have one variable from which I want to create multiple variables all at once?

What I have been doing so far is this:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(var_a = as.numeric(`variable name very long` == "a"),
                    var_b = as.numeric(`variable name very long` == "b"),
                    ...)
```

Except of course there are more than two variables that I want to create. Is there an easier way to do this? And I also use mutate as a way to shorten the variable name. I've also tried creating a function that might be able to do this for whatever variable and value I want it to be since I have to do this often, but I wasn't able to get it to work:

```
varname <- function(newvar, var, value){
           df <- df %>% mutate(newvar = as.numeric(var == "value"))
}

varname("var_a", "`variable name very long`", "a")
```

Any suggestions are deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We could use `map2` to loop over the `unique` elements in the column, along with the `vector` of new column names, `transmute` to create the column, and bind the output with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
un1 <- sort(as.character(unique(df[["variable name very long"]])))
un2 <- str_c('var_', un1)
map2_dfc(un1, un2, ~ df %>%

                       transmute(!! .y :=  +(`variable name very long` == .x))) %>%
       bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 20 x 7
#   `variable name very long`     val var_a var_b var_c var_d var_e
# * <chr>                       <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 c                         -0.710      0     0     1     0     0
# 2 b                         -1.04       0     1     0     0     0
# 3 c                         -0.798      0     0     1     0     0
# 4 e                          0.319      0     0     0     0     1
# 5 b                          1.87       0     1     0     0     0
# 6 b                         -0.317      0     1     0     0     0
# 7 a                         -0.773      1     0     0     0     0
# 8 d                         -1.44       0     0     0     1     0
# 9 a                         -0.348      1     0     0     0     0
#10 a                         -0.421      1     0     0     0     0
#11 e                          1.06       0     0     0     0     1
#12 e                          0.528      0     0     0     0     1
#13 a                          3.13       1     0     0     0     0
#14 e                         -0.546      0     0     0     0     1
#15 e                         -1.05       0     0     0     0     1
#16 d                         -0.687      0     0     0     1     0
#17 e                         -1.13       0     0     0     0     1
#18 b                         -0.489      0     1     0     0     0
#19 a                          1.85       1     0     0     0     0
#20 d                         -0.0376     0     0     0     1     0
```

---

Or another option is `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number(), n = 1,
         newcol = str_c('var_', `variable name very long`)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = newcol, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `model.matrix`

```
cbind(df, model.matrix(~ `variable name very long` -1, df))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- tibble(`variable name very long` = sample(letters[1:5],
      20, replace = TRUE), val = rnorm(20))
```